# Storing an arbitrary R object onto HDD?

Tags: r

I understand that we can export data matrices to `csv` or `xlsx` files.

What about complex objects like `lm`? For example, in my work I might have a list of length 1000, each with a single `lm()` object. Each time I load `R` I have to wait a long time to populate the 1000 length list with these `lm` objects with a `for` loop or a `lapply`.

I would rather just save the list somewhere on my HDD at the end of a session and open it at the start of the next session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use `save()`, together with its counterpart `load()`.

In general, this topic is called "serialization" (see `help(serialize)` ) and R has a lot of support for different formats.

Comment: This changes everything for me!

Comment: Good to know. Next, you may want to peruse the wonders that is `help(connections)` to see the various ways to write and read to and from.